# can't compiler json-framework

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I'm using json-framework to parse json, but when I compile I get the following errors:

xxx/SBJsonStreamParser.h
xxx/SBJsonStreamParser.h:105: error: expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'
xxx.h:106: error: expected a property attribute before 'strong'

etc....

Developer Information：

Version：  4.2 (4D199)
  Location： /Developer
  Applications：
  Xcode：    4.2 (828)
  Instruments：  4.2 (4233)
  Dashcode： 3.0.2 (336)
  SDKs：
  Mac OS X：
  10.6： (10K549)
  10.7： (11C63)
  iPhone OS：
  5.0：  (9A334)
  iPhone Simulator：
  4.3：  (8H7)
  5.0：  (9A334)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check in your Build Settings/Build Options the compiler: Use the default Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 instead of LLVM GCC 4.2.

Comment: What to kin the case that option does not appear?
As for me, I only have "Apple LVVM compiler 2.1" and "GCC 4.2" and none solves the same issue.

Comment: This solution did not work for me, playing around with the c language dialect and or the compiler version increases/decreases the number of errors, but i still cannot get this to work

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONKit instead, it's faster, has less memory leaks, and it might be easier to switch than debugging this issue.

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so maybe manual memory management in the json-framework may be causing the compiler to be unhappy.