# Cannot get Stig Brautaset’s JSON library to work

Tags: xcode, json

I have seen another post similar to this one on the website but the solution provided does not work for me. I will link to the post here 
[can't compiler json-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867983/cant-compiler-json-framework)

I get a lot of error messages when trying to compile this library and I am not sure how to get it to work. I have tried playing around with the compiler version and the c language dialect used by the compiler, this brings the number of errors down from 121 to 4. Any ideas how how I can solve this issue. I will provide the current developer information below:

1. Base SDK : Latest iOs (iOs 4.3)
2. C/C++ compiler version : LLVM GCC 4.2
3. C Language Dialect: Compiler Default
4. Compile source as: Objective-C

This configuration gives me 118 errors.

Changing the C language dialect to ANSI C[-ansi] brings the number of errors down to 4.
Similarly changing the compile source as option to objective c++ brings the number of errors down to 34.

Help with be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Post the errors please! Or, alternatively, you can use my JSON framework https://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON/ and https://github.com/H2CO3/libjsonz

Comment: There are a lot of errors to post on here , but here are a few of them:
 error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
 error: expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'
 error: expected a property attribute before 'strong'
 error: expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'
 error: expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'
 error: request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union
 error: request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union

I shall check out the framework you posted. Thanks

Comment: To resolve the C99-mode error: add -std=gnu99 to your compiler flags. To resolve the property errors: look at the property declarations in the JSON library's header files. To resolve the "request for member..." errors: cast the objets whose properties are accessed to the appropriate type, or use accessor message (i. e., [object property] and [object setProperty:]) insetad of the dot notation.

Comment: I can go about resolving all the errors, but like i mentioned earlier, there are around 121 errors in the code. Surely, there must be something wrong in my config as I know that this library has worked for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was battling with the same problem until I figured out my version of Xcode wasn't the most updated. I had the exact same amount of errors, 118.

Updating to newest Xcode and SBJson classes should fix it. Cheers!